# using Instant class to know particular location time instead of default time zone in java

Tags: java

I am working on with application in which i need to know the time in various locations.To do this i found methods of doing this using zone class which go as like

```
for (String s : zoneList) {
  ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(s);
  ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
  ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();
```

and another way is to use **Instant** class.Using Instant class give me only Greenwich time but I want to know other location time too.How can i do this as like Zone.I surfed a lot on the internet.Can any one help me in this regard.I want to do this using Instant only.

Comment: Well, Instant doesn't have any timezone. So if the goal is to know what time it is at a specific timezone, then Instant is just not what you want. ZonedDateTime is what you need: it's basically an Instant + a timezone.

Comment: Thank you very much I had gone through zonedate time before but my interest in knowing if theres any method in instant class to find different times zones made me spend 1-2 hour on web any way thanks for your time for leaving a comment.